# How to convert the value stored in Observable<any> to a string, in typescript?

Tags: json, string, angular, typescript, observable

Hi I am new to Angular and TypeScript. I need the value of an `Observable` in the format of a string, how does one do this?

the BmxComponent file

```
export class BmxComponent {
    asyncString = this.httpService.getDataBmx();
    currentStock = this.httpService.getDataBmx2(); //this is what I want to covert to a string so I can pass it to onSubmit()

    onSubmit() {
        const asnNumm = this.currentStock; // passing it here changes my database, see below
        this.httpService.sendData({ stock: asnNumm })
            .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

the HttpService file

```
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getDataBmx() {
        return this.http.get('https://the-bicycle-shop.firebaseio.com/products/Bicycles/bmx/stock.json')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    getDataBmx2() {
        return (this.http.get('https://the-bicycle-shop.firebaseio.com/products/Bicycles/bmx/stock.json'));
    }   

    sendData(newStock: any) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(newStock);
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.patch('https://the-bicycle-shop.firebaseio.com/products/Bicycles/bmx.json', body, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .map((data: Response) => data.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }
}
```

the html file

```
<p>{{asyncString | async}}</p> // displays 1234 which is the correct value
<p>{{asyncString}}</p> // displays [object Object]
<p>{{currentStock}}</p> // displays [object Object]
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()">Change Database</button>
```

my database before onSubmit() (used when I click the Change Database button)

```
Bicycles
|
---bmx
    |
    ---stock = 1234;
```

my database after onSubmit()

```
Bicycles
|
--- bmx
     |
     ---stock
         |
         --- _isScalar = false
```

I am using Firebase for this.

I know it will work with a string because I tested it with like this:

```
    onSubmit() {
        const asnNumm = "33333" //the change to test it
        this.httpService.sendData({ stock: asnNumm })
            .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

Which does this to my database

```
Bicycles
|
---bmx
    |
    ---stock = 33333
```

I understand that `currentStock` would hold the same value that is currently stored in my database, so it would make no difference, but I want to change it once I have converted it to a string.

Basically I want to change "stock" in my database, but by a fixed amount each time I press the Change Database button, for example, minus 1 it each time it is pressed.

Comment: share some code please...

Comment: @Roman toString just gives me [object Object]

Comment: @questions see the answer below

Answer (score 6):

Subscribe to the observable to get the result and call `onSubmit` when you receive the value:

```
currentStock = this.httpService.getDataBmx2()
.subscribe(val => this.onSubmit(val));
```

Comment: this won't work because onSubmit() does not accept a value

Comment: Wouldn't be to hard to add a parameter so it does?

Comment: added a parameter, now I get [object Object] again

Comment: Where did you add what parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Objects has `toString` method that you can implement to show the value of object, or convert it to string with `JSON.stringify()` like this

```ts
this.httpService.sendData({ stock: asnNumm })
        .subscribe(
        data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
        error => console.log(error)
        );
```

You have to map to the response object to get data, to get data as text you can query response object

```
getDataBmx2() {
    return this.http.get('https://the-bicycle-shop.firebaseio.com/products/Bicycles/bmx/stock.json')
        .map((response: Response) => response.text());
}


export class BmxComponent {
    currentStock: string;

   this.httpService.getDataBmx2().subscribe(s => this.currentStock = s); //this is what I want to covert to a string so I can pass it to onSubmit()

    onSubmit() {
        const asnNumm = this.currentStock; // passing it here changes my database, see below
```

Comment: can I have an example of this in use? I only get a whole bunch of errors when I implement this.

Comment: I don't have errors, and I'm not sure what you saying.

Comment: @RomanC I think he's trying to use the code in your example as a property definition instead of value.

Comment: @roman I mean can you give an example of how to use this in my code?